Azure GraphQL - ODataErrors when filtering by DateTime
I'm trying to list AccessReview Definition Instances from Azure with GraphQL using this code in C#:
accessReviewInstanceResponse = await graphClient.IdentityGovernance
    .AccessReviews
    .Definitions[accessReview.Id]
    .Instances.GetAsync(config =>
    {
        config.QueryParameters.Filter = "startDateTime ge 2024-06-01T00:00:00Z";
    });

This gives me an Exception Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataErrors: An error has occurred.
How can I filter this query using the startDateTime of the Instance?

AFAIK filtering with startDateTime is not supported for accessReviewInstance resource type. Only $select is supported. Check this and refer this MsDoc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/accessreviewinstance?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Initially when I tried to list the instances with filtering by Date Time, I got the same error as below:
var accessReviewScheduleDefinitionId = "DefinitionID";
var result = await graphClient.IdentityGovernance.AccessReviews.Definitions[accessReviewScheduleDefinitionId]
                .Instances
                .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
 requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "startDateTime ge 2024-06-01T00:00:00Z";
});



Note that: Filtering with startDateTime is not supported for
accessReviewInstance resource type. Only $select is supported. Check this and refer this  MsDoc

You can make use of $select like below:
public class GraphClientExample
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        var tenantId = "TenantID";
        var clientId = "ClentID";
        var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

        var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
            tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var accessReviewScheduleDefinitionId = "DefinitionID";

            var result = await graphClient.IdentityGovernance.AccessReviews.Definitions[accessReviewScheduleDefinitionId]
                .Instances
                .GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "startDateTime" };
                });

            if (result != null && result.Value != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access Review Instances Retrieved:");
                foreach (var instance in result.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Instance ID: {instance.Id}, Start DateTime: {instance.StartDateTime}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No instances found.");
            }
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error Message: {odataError.Error.Message}");
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected Error: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}


